# JavaScript getElementByID is not woking

Tags: javascript

i am not able to get element using 'getElementById()' in java-script, may be i am doing some wrong code.help me out for following code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var ele = document.getElementById('test');

        alert(ele);
    })();
 </script>
<body>
  <div id="test">This is test </div>
</body>
```

Comment: the javascript is running before the element is created .. put the javascript below the div to see results

Comment: Thanks jaromanda .its my silly mistake.

Comment: Also, the title name is misleading; /* The name of the function is  `getElementById()` */

Answer (score -2):

Use either this or put your script after loading all HTML content.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var ele = document.getElementById('test');
        alert(ele.innerHTML);
});
```